# I haven't recieved the funds from my app to my monero wallet?

Tags: transfer

https://minergate.com/blockchain/xmr/transaction/55831a30d4eb2ba105665894809ca4e7b8565531f0882d68c3fa7ca241c22778

I successfully sent btc to my monero gui wallet but it's been hours and I still have yet to see it in my wallet. What happened?

Comment: Please have a look at the guide I linked. Let me know if you need any further assistance.